# Font weight BOLD using formula in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheet to make some calculations.

At the bottom of my table I need SUM, AVG and some others and everything is fine.

But I made a long cell with all the text, like this:

```
="Hi at all, this is my report: "&SUM(B:B)&" are the sum of my fingers, "&AVG(C:C)&" is the avg of my sons."
```

and so on.

Everything works. But I need to bold the `SUM(B:B)`.

I won't use single cells for math results.

I tried with `....<b>"&SUM(B:B)&"</b>....` but obviously I take `<b></b>` in my cell and not the bold font weight.

How to style from formula in cell?

Comment: Currently that feature is not available in Google Sheets. You can read more about the limited "partial cell formatting" features here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/asZ_rbsVm9Q;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/format$20partial.

Comment: I find it odd that they offer CHAR(10) for line breaks in a formula, yet they don't offer italics or bold in the formulas.

Comment: It's not odd when you realise that CHAR(10) is just a character like any other, but bold or italics is metadata. Line breaks are available because line breaks are characters. If bold was a different set of characters like upper case then they would "offer" that as well.

Answer (score 13):

Recently I had the same problem, but I found a solution. This solution works well in google sheets.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E3,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

If you want to improve your formula, use the characters below:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Amazing. It killed my braincells .. but still amazing dude.

Comment: For those considering this approach, please be mindful that [abusing unicode characters in this way (counter to how they were intended to be used) creates an accessibility nightmare](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/118149/can-screen-readers-interpret-unicode-styles-fonts-such-as-bold-and-italics). **Please be considerate of those using assistive technologies.**

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible.

---

My own solution is at the bottom, but I find the one added by Adrian Mihai Nemes here to be cleaner. So, I have expanded that solution here to work for lowercase as well as uppercase and numbers. This should work for text containing anything, including newlines, single quotes, emojis, etc.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B25,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

---

For my own solution, this will bold all lowercase, uppercase, and numbers. It should work for text containing just about anything, including newlines, single quotes, etc. (perhaps not emojis?).

Just replace the single `A2` reference with whatever it is you want bolded:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("", UNICHAR(QUERY(UNICODE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
    REGEXREPLACE(
        REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2&""
            ,"([^a-zA-Z0-9])","$1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(1)&CHAR(127))
            ,"'","''")
            ,"([a-z])","$1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119738)&CHAR(127))
            ,"([A-Z])","$1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119744)&CHAR(127))
            ,"([0-9])","$1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(120735)&CHAR(127))
    ,"'","''")
,CHAR(127))), UNICHAR(160))), "select Col1+Col2-1 label Col1+Col2-1 ''",0))))
```

**Overview:**
For each character group (lowercase, uppercase, numbers) we're using stringed together `REGEXREPLACE` calls to append special separator characters along with the base unicode character for that group's bold font right after.

So for example, `Hi-1` becomes `"H"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119743)&CHAR(127)&"i"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119737)&CHAR(127)&"-"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(1)&CHAR(127)&"1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(120734)&CHAR(127)`.

Once we have this new string, we split on the `CHAR(127) and transform, so each of these characters are on their own row. So the example now becomes:

```
"H"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119743)
"i"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(119737)
"-"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(1)
"1"&UNICHAR(160)&UNICHAR(120734)
```

Next, we split on the `UNICHAR(160)` character:

```
"H", UNICHAR(119743)
"i", UNICHAR(119737)
"-", UNICHAR(1)
"1", UNICHAR(120734)
```

We use the `UNICODE()` function to convert the actual characters along with their corresponding UNICHAR into their unicode numbers:

```
72, 119744
105, 119738
45, 1
49, 120735
```

Now, we use the `QUERY()` function as a way of summing each of these rows individually. That's where the `"select Col1+Col2-1 label Col1+Col2-1 ''"` comes in. It is adding column 1 to column 2 and taking away the 1 extra from the base unicode value, and then preventing a heading label from being added to the function output.
So, now we get:

```
119815
119842
45
120783
```

We use the next `UNICHAR()` function to convert these to their unicode characters, which at this point is the corresponding bolded character:

```
-
```

Lastly, we use a `JOIN()` with an empty string `""` delimiter to combine it all back into a single string.

```
-
```

p.s. If you're curious why the different character groups need to be split up, it's because each group lines up with their corresponding bold characters in order, but not all 3 character groups in a row. There are some extra characters between the normal type groups that you don't see in the bold section of unicode. Thus, each character group has to be given its own base unicode value to be added to that normal character's unicode value.

p.p.s. If you wanted to add more characters, you would just need to add another wrapping `REGEXREPLACE()` with the correct character group, and the `UNICHAR()` with the correct base unicode value for that group, and then add that new group to the exclusions from the first `REGEXREPLACE()`. Happy to explain this further if required.

p.p.p.s. The `REGEXREPLACE()` with the single quote `'` being replaced with two single quotes `''` is needed because when we split the characters to their own cells, Google Sheets actually considers a leading single quote as a special character and removes it. So effectively, two single quotes get converted to one single quote after splitting.

Comment: Adrian Mihai Nemes's answer using multiple `SUBSTITUTE()` calls just seems way easier and cleaner than this, lol.

Answer (score 5):

I updated Adrian's formula to style to sans-serif characters instead of serif ones if anyone needs it. It includes both lower and upper case letters, as well as numbers.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

Answer (score 4):

At the current time, in Google Sheets you cannot bold partial components of any formula. The solution mentioned using the 'B' or bold icon only works if the desired bold selection is an entire cell containing a formula, or partial of a cell that does not contain a formula.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am giving 2 solutions. 1st based on Adrian Mihai. Just changing the multiple substitutes to an iteration and reduction:

```
=REDUCE(E3,
    {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},
    LAMBDA(prev, new, SUBSTITUTE(prev, LEFT(new,1), RIGHT(new,2)))
)
```

It uses the same `SUBSTITUTE` but does iteration, so we may add up in the list.

---

Another solution is based on UNICODE transformations. This will transform A-Z, a-z and 0-9. Rest of the characters will be retained as it is:

```
=REDUCE("",
        SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(E3,
                        "(.)",
                        "$1"&UNICHAR(1)
                ),
                UNICHAR(1)
        ), // Splitting the string into characters
        LAMBDA(prev,
                this,
                prev & IFS(
                                AND(UNICODE(this)>= 48, UNICODE(this)<= 58), // Change 0-9
                                        UNICHAR(UNICODE(this)+ 120734),
                                AND(UNICODE(this)>=65, UNICODE(this)<=90), // Change A-Z
                                        UNICHAR(UNICODE(this)+ 119743),
                                AND(UNICODE(this)>=97,UNICODE(this)<= 122), // Change a-z
                                        UNICHAR(UNICODE(this)+ 119737),
                                TRUE, // No change
                                        this
                        )
        )
)
```

Explanation:
The `SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE...` is used to split the string into characters. It should have been possible with `SPLIT(E3,"")`, but SPLIT function gives error with blank, so adding one special character `UNICHAR(1)` and then splitting by that.

Next, iterating over and reducing the characters, checking their unicode values and in case it falls between desired ranges (as commented), replacing them with their bold equivalents. Eg. In case of 'A', UNICODE("A") will be 65, now adding 119743 to 65 becomes 119808 which is for the bold A. Similarly for other characters.

The final `TRUE` condition is added for the remaining characters like @,# etc. which cannot be changed hence will appear as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Adrian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555199/13641358) code for italic:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(H3:H,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z","")
```

This site below can give you other unicode ideas for text substitutions:
https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue at the moment. Spent a decent amount of time figuring it out before I realized it cannot be done. The reason for this is that Google spreadsheets does not allow bits of a query to have bold/italics/underline to it.

The only workaround I have found is to do it manually . Let the query run , and highlight the section of the string you want with a different formatting option.

Answer (score -2):

To make any of the cells bold just make a conditional format for the cell/range/array and choose bold.

Comment: The question is about formatting a part of the cell, not the entire cell.