# Is it possible to formatting bold in excel formula?

Tags: excel-formula

[format sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmtpZ.png)

Here I want to add text a1+b1+c1, But I want to **bold** b1 text like **command module** will be bold.
Is it possible to bold this word.

2. [date formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF9US.png)

Is it possible to bold date. suppose Date: **08/01/2017**

Comment: If you always want the text bold, just bold the cell. If you only want to bold it if the value is a date, you should be able to use conditional formatting. https://support.office.com/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6B6F7C2A-5D62-45A1-8F67-584A76776D67

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265593/font-weight-bold-using-formula-in-cell/63555199#63555199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265593/font-weight-bold-using-formula-in-cell/63555199#63555199)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.  Excel doesn't provide such functionality to apply rich text formatting to part of the formula.

But you can possibly insert a `Text Box` over the result cell to achieve this.  Here is a link that you can read: [Formatting part of a formula](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/368294-fomatting-part-of-a-formula-to-be-bold-font.html)

Comment: This other forum thread also details two different text-box based approaches by two different authors, both are quite clever and would suit different purposes: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/formatting-text-bold-within-a-formula.75061/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot format text to italic, but you could change the basic latin letters to corresponding italic unicode characters:

```
    Function ITALIC(orig As String) As String
        Dim result As String
        Dim c As Long
        result = ""
        For i = 1 To Len(orig)
            c = WorksheetFunction.Unicode(Mid(orig, i, 1))
            If c > 64 And c < 91 Then c = c + 120263
            If c > 64 And c < 123 Then c = c + 120257
            result = result & WorksheetFunction.Unichar(c)
        Next i
        ITALIC = result
    End Function
```

You may change the text to many other forms as well.
https://lingojam.com/ItalicTextGenerator

Comment: What a great idea! I didn't think to use bolded characters! Since the OP asked about bold text, here's the bold text generator I used: https://www.madeintext.com/bold-text-generator/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can apply rich text formatting to the cells that contain the formula, why not use more than 1 cell and eliminate the display of line between them so the 2 cells look like 1.  Then put the word "Date:" in the first cell flush right margin and in the cell next to it, put the formula to gather the date, formatting the cell to flush left margin, and bold that cell.