# How can I bold a part of a text that contains a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

*The situation :*

I got a cell that contains this formula :

```
="Made in Paris, the "&TEXTE(AUJOURDHUI();"jj/mm/aaaa")&"."
```

And it comes out as :

> Made in Paris, the 23/03/2022.

*My approach of the problem:*

`Worksheets("AAA").Range("C8").Characters(30, 66).Font.Bold = True`

It doesn't work because there is a formula, I think.

Now I need you all help to make it look like :

> Made in Paris, the **23/03/2022**.

Comment: VBA can not format part of a formula to bold.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld find a solution, u can see it under.

Comment: Try the link below [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265593/font-weight-bold-using-formula-in-cell/63555199#63555199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265593/font-weight-bold-using-formula-in-cell/63555199#63555199)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it with the formula in the cell.
But you can put the formula in a VBA macro.
And you could trigger the macro to run on certain events, or trigger it manually.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub boldDate()
    Dim r As Range
    Const sText As String = "Made in Paris, "
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim Start As Long, Length As Long
Start = Len(sText) + 1
Length = 10

Set r = Selection 'Or specify the cell where you want this written.

With r
    .Value = sText & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    .Characters(Start, Length).Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a work around (substituting alphanumeric characters for bold unicode versions) but you can use this formula if you'd rather not use VBA, replacing "E3" with the cell or string you want

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E3,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z","")
```

Formatted with some line breaks so its a bit easier to read:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E3,
"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),
"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),
"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),
"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"0",""),"1",""),
"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),
"9",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),
"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),
"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),
"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z","")
```

Comment: You can't use formatting within a formula!

Comment: Clever, but ugly solution.  It would be great if there was a function like UNIX's `tr` for this purpose.

@Ike, it's not formatting!  It's using different characters! !!1!11!!11!!