# Can Words in String Be Formatted as Bold or Underlined in google sheets in 2023

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In the past, converting part of a string using formulas to format a string as bold or underlined could [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265593/font-weight-bold-using-formula-in-cell) be accomplished in google sheets.

However, this question is time dependent as functions are added. Has this changed as of todays date?

For example, could I get from yes, no in A1 to **yes**, no using a formula like: `subsitute(a1,"yes", bold("yes"))`

Comment: Don't repost - if you want more answers [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).